# Survey with two simple random samples without repetition

Tags: self-study, estimation, sampling, sample, survey-sampling

I have an particular exercise of sampling survey, or sampling theory, which I report below.

> One is interested in knowing the price per gram of gold produced by 100 companies. A monthly survey of a sample of 5 companies
> is conducted for this purpose. The following table shows the prices
> per gram of gold collected in March and April and the respective
> sample means and variances.
>
> [image: Table]
>
> Assume one of the following sampling methods was adopted:
>
> *Method No. 1*: A simple random sample without repetition of 5 companies in March and one of 5 companies in April are selected such
> that the two samples are completely independent;
>
> *Method No. 2*: A simple random sample without repetition of 5 companies is selected in March and the same sample is also used in April.
>
> Estimate yourself:
>
> - The absolute change in the average price per gram of gold between March and April;
> - The average price per gram in the March-April bimonthly period. We compare the efficiency of the estimators between the two sampling methods shown above for parameters (1) and (2) and comment on the results.

I've chosen Method No. 1 and I've done the first two points:

- Absolute change: `mean(April) - mean(March) = 58.8 - 58.2 = 0.6`
- Average price: `(58.8 + 58.2)/2 = 58.49`

My problem is how to evaluate the efficiency of the estimators, which they've based on the same sample method (SRSWOR). But the point is if I've well calculated the estimator of the Method No. 1 because I've just used the two sample means.

About Method No. 2 I was thinking to use the sample mean of March, but I'm not sure because the absolute change between two months would be null.

Thank you everyone.

## **UPDATE**

I've made some reflections, and I lay them out for you.

1. Absolute change:

- Method No.1: I calculate the difference between the means: $\hat{y}_{April} - \hat{y}_{March} = 58.8 - 58.2 = 0.6$
- Method No. 2: since the exercise assumes that March and April have same sample, the change is equal to zero: $\hat{y}_{April} - \hat{y}_{March} = 58.2 - 58.2 = 0$

2.a) Average price of the period:

- Method No. 1: the average price is a combination of two prices: $\hat{y} = (\hat{y}_{April} + \hat{y}_{March})/2 = (58.8 + 58.2)/2 = 58.5$
- Method No. 2: the average price is equal to $\hat{y}_{March}$ because we assume that March and April have same sample.

2.b) Efficiency:
I assume that the Sample Variance into table are $s^2$. I calculate the variance $Var(\bar{Y})$ of two samples with the following formula:
$$
Var(\bar{Y}) = \frac {1 - f}{n} s^2 = \frac {1 - 0.05}{5} s^2 = 0.19 \cdot s^2
$$

Let's proceed:

- $Var(\bar{Y}_{March}) = 1.577$
- $Var(\bar{Y}_{April}) = 1.615$

Finally, I compute the ratio:
$$
\frac{Var(\bar{Y}_{April})}{Var(\bar{Y}_{March})} \approx 1.0241
$$

The variance of Method No. 2 is less efficient.

Even assuming the absence of the $(1 - f)/n$ term because practice suggests that for $f < 0.05$ it is negligible, I have the same result.

If I did something wrong please write to me.
Thank you.

## UPDATE No. 2

I have also thought to solve in the following way. Sorry if I make a mistake, but I want to try differently.

I assume that the two methods assume to combine the samples in the following way:

- Method No.1:

[image]

- Method No.2:

[image]

The sample of the Method No. 1 has calculated in the following: the unit no. 1 of March sums with the unit no. 1 of April and so on. With the Method No. 2 I multiplied the units of March by two.

However, I can't compare anything because the two points of 1) asks to calculate an absolute change, the average price in the bimonth and the efficiency of the estimators. What am I doing wrong in my approach toward the problem?

## UPDATE No. 3

I have solved the exercise. In practice, the Update No. 1 was right. Now I discuss the motivation.

- Method No. 1: this method assumes the variable $W = \bar{Y}_1 - \bar{Y}_2$ with variance $Var(W) = Var(\bar{Y}_1) + Var(\bar{Y}_2)$ because the two samples are independent.
- Method No. 2: this method uses the sample of March which also applies it to April. Hence, we have as mean and variance the same statistics of March.

I choose the Method No. 1. Hence:

- Absolute change: $\bar{y}_{April} - \bar{y}_{March} = 58.8 - 58.2 = 0.6$
- Average price: $(\bar{y}_{April} + \bar{y}_{March})/2 = (58.8+58.2)/2 = 58.5$
- Efficiency:
  $$
  \frac{Var(W)}{Var(\bar{y}_{March})} = \frac{Var(\bar{y}_{April}) + Var(\bar{y}_{March})}{Var(\bar{y}_{March})} = \frac{16.8}{8.3} \approx 2.024
  $$

The variable $W$ is less efficient than $\bar{y}_{March}$.